# Cannot post on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, asking-questions, code-block

Why do my posts keep failing? I am trying to ask a question relating to C# and ASP.NET and it keeps making me verify I'm not a robot or script or just spins for a long time and then says it can't! I can't find a help forum or a person to contact on this issue, can anyone point me in the right direction? Just to be clear, it's only this one specific question I keep trying to ask. It makes no sense to me.

Actually, posting line by line, can response . write mess up stack overflow? All of it will post until I get here:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('{0}')</script>", ddnEmail.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

I had to mess with it until it would post...

Comment: Are you using Https Everywhere or accessing the site over https?

Comment: Why do I keep getting down voted on what, in my opinion, is a legitimate Question. I cannot post an issue I am having. I ask for assistance, and instead I get a flurry of down votes?

Comment: You were able to post this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097730/unable-to-post-on-stack-overflow and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097487/handle-event-not-firing-when-dynamic-control-is-being-created just a few minutes ago.

Comment: @BradLarson: Because he didn't have the `script alert` inside

Comment: @BradLarson That was a mess up, at some point it did accidentally go through. That's not the actual question though, so I deleted it.

Comment: @BradLarson Also, the second one is almost the same question as this one. Like I said, I CAN post, just not my question.

Comment: I think it's a matter of formatting. Format it as code and it will be ok. I just tried (but it needs peer review) and it's ok then (at least for me)

Comment: @ThomasW. I just attempted to post it again with the 'code' formatting and it still hung up and failed...

Comment: @ThomasW.  I was able to post it here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22098180/edit
but had to do the same funky thing with the spacing in the code.

Comment: You appear to have gotten most of the (currently 5) down votes in response to the original versions of your question. You had initially not posted any details of what you were doing, and had in fact doubled up the content of your post. (perhaps it wasn't initially long enough?) Since then, you've improved it with details, and it's a decent question... and you've gotten up votes. Here; have another one!

Answer (score 5):

The question you're trying to post contains items which look like a JavaScript injection to StackOverflow itself. If you format the code portion of your question as code (prefixed by 4 spaces), it should be fine. In the preview it should looke like this:

```
<script>alert("This is my evil code which I don't want to execute on Stackoverflow")</script>
```